# Lazy menu construction in Vim

Tags: vim

I make a lot of use of the GUI menus in gvim, which I create on-the-fly using the ex command `:menu`, and its variations. Some of my menus take a long time to construct (for example, needing to glob a large directory).

1. Is it possible to have a lazy sub-menu which is only constructed when you try to access it?
2. Alternatively, with the new `job_start()` functionality, is it possible to display a menu while its sub-menus are still being constructed in the background?

Either of these solutions would be a big improvement in responsiveness.

Comment: Have a look at `$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim` and search for `do_syntax_sel_menu`.

Comment: Note: jobs are for external processes, not for executing vim script code in background.